# Should this question be split into five?

Tags: discussion

[How does a Flaming Sphere's movement work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49347/clarification-of-flaming-sphere-spell-mechanics)

> Question text:
>   Regarding Flaming Sphere:
>
> The sphere does damage when it occupies the same space as a creature. When I move it into a creature's space to attack, the sphere stops moving for the round. If the creature and sphere don't move, is this attack automatic on my next round, and is the sphere stuck in the same space as the creature until the creature moves?
>
> If I am able to move the sphere out of the space occupied by the creature, does it not do damage to that creature again until it moves back into that creatures space?
>
> Does the sphere move only in a straight line, or can I have it move in a circle (North 5 feet, East 5 feet, South 5 feet, West 5 feet, North 5 feet, South 5 feet)?
>
> Does directing the sphere to move provoke an attack of opportunity?
>
> Can a caster have two spheres at the same time, using two move actions to direct them both during a round? If so, can both spheres attack a single target

Comment: It does need a better title though…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

The questions are closely related, and it would be confusing for the asker and the answers to answer in multiple places.  The rules to cite will likely be similar between the questions.

Comment: I was going to disagree about the last two sub-questions on AoO and doubling the spell, but then I realised the common element was the spell's movement rules and even the last two sub-questions could be tied to the rest with a retitling.